# Tracking redirects Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, redirect

**Is there a way in PHP to know if the current script (page) came from an apache 301 redirect?**

Additional details to set the stage for this question:

We just completed a website merge, retiring one web site and sending it's traffic to a similar sister website which included 100s of individual 301 redirects for products, categories. We would like to track transactions that originated from the retired website URLs vs those originating from the current URL. Basically, as an order completed, we want to know which URL it had originated from, redirected from the old vs direct traffic from the new.

Currently the 301 redirects are performed via a separate file included in the httpd.conf file. This separate file contains 100s of "Redirect 301 /source /destination" directives.

My plan was to have PHP sniff out these redirects, store the original URL domain as a session variable, then access that session variable at order completion in order to connect it to that original domain.

For this to work, the landing page script would need to know if it is the result of a redirect. Which leads to the question: Is there a way in PHP to know if the current script (page) came from an Apache 301 redirect?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: _“Is there a way in PHP to know if the current script (page) came from an Apache 301 redirect?”_ - not without you explicitly storing that info somewhere, or passing it along with the redirect URL itself. PHP only knows URL X was requested, but it has no idea what brought the _client_ to do so in the first place.

Comment: You could parse your logs and track which requests triggered a 301 return status.  You would know what the request was, what was returnned.  Or use Google Analytics (or other similar software) which keeps a track of requests done on your site via Javascript code in your pages.  But PHP, nope.